# how can I filter out unwanted search results in Alfred (ie node_modules folder, caches)

Tags: finder, spotlight, search, alfred

Been a user of Alfred for a long time, however whenever I search anything I get a lot of FUD results due to alfred also indexing all my web project `node_modules` directories.

Is there any way to path-match and exclude all results from within a `/node_modules/` directory? This would greatly improve the utility of the search.

Comment: Look into using a *script filter*, which allows you to customise the results returned in the *Alfred* search box.  But they’re also quite a ball ache to set up.

Answer (score 14):

Go to Preferences -> Spotlight -> Privacy (TAB)
Then add the folders you want to exclude to that list.

Comment: A couple things seem missing. How does this match paths for dozens or hundreds of folders? Are you saying Alfred only uses spotlight?

Comment: In Alfred 4 there is no "Spotlight" tab anymore

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg They mean System Preferences, not Alfred Preferences. System Preferences has a Spotlight section, and that has a Privacy tab; but it does seem to only list *specific* folders, rather than being able to specify a pattern (e.g. "ignore node_modules everywhere you see it").

Answer (score 5):

You can also add `alfred:ignore` to the spotlight comments of the folder that you want exclude, in your case the `node_modules` folder.

Comment: Thankfully you don't have to do this via the Finder interface. You can use the AppleScript `tell application "Finder" to set comment of item POSIX file "/path/to/file" to "alfred:ignore"`. However note `alfred:ignore` only applies to the folder itself, not its descendants.

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been in [discussion](https://www.alfredforum.com/topic/1412-excluding-folders) on the Alfred Forum since 2013 and unfortunately the answer is that Alfred can't really omit "node_modules" without you tagging all folders with the `alfred:ignore` tag. This would of course involve yet another script so it's overkill.

There is an alternative solution though: switch to yarn 2 and this issue with Alfred will implicitly go away! They built a new system-wide caching mechanism which avoids installing "node_modules" in every node project.

https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry